# What's the name for saying "no" but not meaning that?

Tags: phrases, verbs, idioms

What is it called when someone says no, but actually doesn't mean that?

Imagine this situation: when two lovers have had an argument then one of them is trying to apologise but the other one (usually the girl) says "no, I don't forgive you." but she isn't really angry. She just want him to insist more. She says no in a some kind of seductive or cute way.

What is this behavior called?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question, which says that no means keep going.

Comment: Insouciant antiphrasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OED **equivocate** (v.)

> **4.** intransitive. **In bad sense: ‘To mean one thing and express another’ (Johnson); to prevaricate.**
>
> 1590   E. Sandys Europæ Speculum (1632) 102   *Making it lawfull for
> them to æquivocate with their adversaries in their answeres.*
>
> 1849   T. B. Macaulay Hist. Eng. II. 379   *The witness shuffled,
> equivocated, pretended to misunderstand the questions.*
>
> 2018 Charles Harrington Elster How to Tell Fate from Destiny 107  ·  *To equivocate is to use evasive or ambiguous language so as to avoid commitment or to willfully mislead. When you equivocate you express yourself in a subtle and evasive manner, using ambiguous words and double meanings so as to mislead*

Noun: **equivocation**

Comment: Seductive and cute?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Throw in a couple of adverbs...

Comment: So the answer is inadequate.

Comment: The inadequacy, if any, seems to come from a desire to be spoon-fed. On its own, it is enough.